# SSIS error The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'database_principals', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Error: 229)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

The SSIS job was correctly running but now the job fails and gives the error

> TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services
> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'database_principals', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)

The owner of catalog is dbo and another windows user. I tried to check the ssis_admin for dbo but cannot. also I try to uncheck the db_denydatareader and db_denydatawriter but I cannot to. Could  you please help me?

Comment: The error msg is very clear.... "also I try to uncheck the db_denydatareader and db_denydatawriter but I cannot" - then you don't have sufficient permissions. Not sure how you think we can elevate your perms!

Comment: I connect to database with SA user but I do not know how I can give these permissions. 
I know you cannot elevate my perms But Maybe some one can guide me how I can give permissions

Comment: What do you get if you run the following: `select database_principal_id() `